# Install composer dependencies that reference VS Team Services git repo during build

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a project that lives in a Visual Studio Team Services git repo. Inside of that there is a composer file which references other VSTS git repos as dependencies.

Here's an example of what the composer file looks like:

```
{
        "name": "mybiz/app",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://mybiz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/myproject/_git/mybiz-app",
            "reference": "someguid"
 }
```

The build definition (also in Team Services) is very simple with a task that executes "composer install". When I run the build  I get this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information

Installing dependencies from lock file

Installing mybiz/app (1.0.0)
Cloning someguid
Authentication required (mybiz.visualstudio.com):
   Username:

[RuntimeException]
Aborted
```

I have a PAT created and alternate credentials setup in Team Services, but I don't know how to utilize them on the build agent and/or if they're even the right answer to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the URL to this format:

```
"url": "https://alternativeusername:alternativepassword@youraccount.visualstudio.com/_git/yourproject",
```

Comment: Thanks, Eddie! I'll give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: Eddie, instead of having the password out there like that, is there a more secure way? Thanks.

Comment: @AspiringTFSGuru You can add a secret variable in your build definition and set its value to your password. And then use replace token task to transfer this value into "composer.json" file. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Comment: That works great, Eddie. I decided to use a PAT instead of alternative credentials, so the URL looks like this:
"url": "https://AnyUsername:PAT@youraccount.visualstudio.com/_git/yourproject",

And with the replace token, it looks like this:
"https://AnyUsername:#{git-vsts-token}#@youraccount.visualstudio.com/_git/yourproject",

Comment: @Eddie Chen - MSFT is it possible to use ssh url?

Comment: Composer doesn't seem to honor the "AnyUserName:PAT", even if I hard code it in composer.json. I'm instead using auth.json. I generate this with a `Bash@3` task I invoke before `composer install` that runs this inline script: `'echo ''{"http-basic": {"youraccount.visualstudio.com": {"username": "AnyUsername", "password": "$(git-vsts-token)" }}}'' > auth.json'`.  Would love any suggestions on how to improve on this. It would be great if DevOps handled this out of the box - I spent at least an hour trying to figure this out.